# How to get curl to return actual website data

Tags: curl, libcurl

When I go to thelibertydaily.com with a browser, the site information comes in in full.  When I use curl to get the info, I get this only:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how to use curl to get the real info from the site?

Thanks

Comment: Check out https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html `curl -L` for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `curl --help` all the options for `curl` will be returned. The one you are interested in is:

```
-L, --location      Follow redirects (H)
```

So, execute your command as:

```
curl -L url
```